# Voice modulator through Javascript possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, media-player, getusermedia, audiocontext

I'm trying to build an app that will take mic input, modulate it, and then broadcast it as an audio source that my web browser can then use.

Use cases for this would be like on a video call. If I need to change my voice to artificially make it louder or perform other modulations, I would use this app.

Right now I have the first 2 steps of getting the mic input and modulating it done, but I'm stuck on the third. How do I broadcast it back to the system as a viable audio source (or in the terms of the app, how to do I get the video call to pick up the sound I'm outputting)?

Some of the ideas I've seen so far have been trying to play the modulated sound back into the microphone object but I don't see a reliable way to do that.

In summary: Is there any way with Javascript (in the browser) or NodeJS to take a sound and register or broadcast it as an audio source that the browser can use?

I don't even know if this is possible and if the answer is "no", then please answer that. There might be some security issues with this that I am totally overlooking. In the end, this question is if nothing, conceptional.

Comment: Could WebSockets help with this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: @Rauññ I am not the one hosting the server is the problem

Comment: I think is possible, you need to create a virtual input signal to be accepted by the browser, then feed that virtual input from your app

https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/